# How to access phpmyadmin on DDEV Windows 10 pro localhost with SSL record too long error

Tags: docker, ssl, drupal, phpmyadmin, ddev

I am using DDEv and Docker with Windows 10 pro to set up a localhost install of drupal 8.8 using Composer. I have set up and configured the local drupal installation (it is a fresh install) and it appears to be running correctly, but in the admin section of the drupal site I receive a warning to change write permissions of sites/default/settings.php.

I tried to change settings using Filezilla, but it appears that local files in Filezilla do not provide access to write permissions? When I right-click the file in Filezilla, no permissions option appears.

Following troubleshooting tips from ddev, I tried to access phpmyadmin at https://mysitename.ddev.site:8036

Instead of loading phpmyadmin, I got the following error message:

> Secure Connection Failed

An error occurred during a connection to dmckimep.ddev.site:8036. SSL received a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length.

Error code: SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG

```
The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because the authenticity of the received data could not be verified. 

Please contact the website owners to inform them of this problem.
```

I've been searching around for a couple of hours now and do not find a solution to this. I ran ddev describe and all seems fine with the installation. The drupal site in the container seems to run okay. There are no port conflicts present so far as I have found, so I am not sure why I cannot get access to phpmyadmin.

I am a relative newbie in terms of skills, but have successfully maintained drupal 4-7 on localhost with XAMPP and my web host. Now I am wrestling with the move to drupal 8/composer/docker/ddev. Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Hi and welcome to ddev! ddev doesn't support https for phpmyadmin. I'm not sure why, haven't explored that, and it's probably possible to do. But `ddev describe` doesn't offer you an https URL. Can you say more about why you want https for phpmyadmin? Note that there isn't really a security impact, because the communication with phpmyadmin is just on your machine.

Comment: That did the trick! Thanks! I did not intentionally specify https: just pasted the :8036 at the end of the top level URL. I will have to be careful about checking such details. I have successfully opened phpmyadmin now. Thanks again!

Comment: Hmmm... Hope I am not being rude--tried to find a way to "accept" or up-vote your solution, but don't find it yet. Will keep looking...

Comment: @femrich We appreciate you trying to be a contentious Stack Overflow user. The reason you can't accept this is because it's posted as a "comment." Only "answers" can be accepted. If rfay wishes to post the comment as an answer, you'll be able to accept it then. I'm glad you were able to solve the problem.

Comment: You're not being rude - you're finding your way around! Per @Isaac Bennetch I added a formal answer, you can now mark that as the accepted answer. 

When answering someone on Stack Overflow it's often best to start out the conversation with a comment IMO, to make sure that the question is fully understood.

Comment: Thanks @rfay. I marked the answer as accepted, but apparently that does not become visible until I get some more points for participation. I really appreciate the help!

Comment: Thanks, @IsaacBennetch; I appreciate the guidance and support!

Comment: You got it accepted! Congrats, and looking forward to your reputation here ever increasing as you help others.

Comment: Thanks. @rfay! I appreciate the help and encouragement!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Update 2023-11-29**: DDEV uses the ddev-phpmyadmin add-on, and has had https support for PHPMyAdmin for years now, `ddev describe` will show you the URL. As explained below by @HEYDANNY, you install PhpMyAdmin with `ddev get ddev-phpmyadmin && ddev restart` and can launch it with `ddev phpmyadmin`, and it works fine with https.

Comment: I'd like it. now I have to add a different port and change SSL to hop over to PHPmyadmin. just a port change should be enough. It's also cleaner / nicer to support both http and https.

Comment: There's a typo in add-on name, it's `ddev/ddev-phpmyadmin`

Comment: don't forget "ddev restart"

Answer (score 7):

Since ddev version 1.22.0 `phpmyadmin` support has changed to a DDEV add-on.

You need to install it `ddev get ddev/ddev-phpmyadmin && ddev restart` and then you can execute `ddev phpmyadmin` to call `phpmyadmin`.

See: https://github.com/ddev/ddev/releases/tag/v1.22.0

Comment: Thanks, it worked !! 
"ddev restart" is important.

Answer (score 1):

Just as a general add on, after `ddev start` you can run `ddev phpmyadmin` in order to open PHPMyAdmin for the current project database in the browser.