# How to change file permissions in localhost Windows 10 pro/docker/ddev container for Drupal site?

Tags: docker, drupal, windows-10, file-permissions, ddev

I have installed a drupal 8.8 site using Composer on a Windows 10 pro system and docker and ddev as the development environment.

The drupal site seems to be functioning normally: I see no errors in the drupal log nor when I run ddev describe.

The only exception: Drupal gives me a warning that sites/default/settings.php needs to be write protected. In the past I have done this on a live site using Filezilla, but this is a development only site and it seems Filezilla does not apply permissions on local files--at least, when I right-click the file locally, I do not find a command for changing permissions.

I tried changing the write permissions with Windows 10 itself, but that did not seem to have any effect--I suspect for windows those are different kinds of permissions.

I poked around online and saw something that made me think I could use phpmyadmin to change permissions. Got caught up in that and struggled with it, until getting some help here ([How to access phpmyadmin on DDEV Windows 10 pro localhost with SSL record too long error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59231424/how-to-access-phpmyadmin-on-ddev-windows-10-pro-localhost-with-ssl-record-too-lo)) but it turns out you can't change file permissions with phpmyadmin, apparently.

I tried to use the address that connected me to phpmyadmin in my browser to connect with Putty, but Putty tells me the host does not exist.

So the help I am looking for: how can I change file permissions for sites/default/settings.php in Windows 10 pro localhost running docker/ddev development environment for my drupal site?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you're talking about this warning?

[image: settings.php warning]

First, you can ignore this warning completely. You're on a local development environment, and so you shouldn't have any concerns about the permissions of settings.php.

Unfortunately, in a Windows environment, you can't make simple permissions changes as Drupal 8 is suggesting that you do.

Note that settings.ddev.php explicitly provides the skip_permissions_hardening option, `$settings['skip_permissions_hardening'] = TRUE;` to tell Drupal 8 *not* to try to change permissions on sites/default and sites/default/settings.php *because* it's just a dev environment and because when Drupal does these things it just makes things harder.

However, to make most things easier on Windows (doesn't solve that problem)...

**Use nfs_mount_enabled**

I see there are loads of problems with the new "official" Drupal 8.8.0 composer build on Windows. Most of them are due to the composer build making some assumptions about the ability to set time and ownership, but the docker mount used by default (CIFS) has everything owned by root, so the container can't change permissions (even thought they're wide open).

I found that I could get by all of these things by using NFS to mount into the container, and you'll also find it improves performance quite a lot. Set up for NFS by following the instructions at https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/stable/users/performance/#windows-nfs-setup

Comment: Thanks very much. This question was the tip of my iceberg, and your reply gets to some of the depth of my issues right now--the 8.8 installs I am doing keep crashing. I will try your suggested NFS mount solution and see if it works for me. Thanks again!

Comment: I'm a bit of a newbie: What is the git bash command to download and run the script in this case, please?: To enable winnfsd as a service, please download, inspect and run the script "windows_ddev_nfs_setup.sh" installed by the installer (or download from windows_ddev_nfs_setup.sh) in a git-bash session on windows.

Comment: As I understand, I would open Git Bash and run: 
wget -0 -https://github.com/drud/ddev/blob/master/scripts/windows_ddev_nfs_setup.sh | bash
Is this correct, @rfay? Thanks!

Comment: Oops! Correction: 

'wget -0 -https://raw.githubusercontent.com/drud/ddev/master/scripts/windows_ddev_nfs_setup.sh | bash'

Comment: No, please just follow the instructions. Download the file, open it to inspect it, and run it in a git-bash window.

Comment: unfortunately it is my confusion over how to do those things that led to this. Would you recommend I undo what I have done with the file at this point, and then try again to follow the instructions?

Comment: In a git-bash window, in the directory where the script is (for example /c/Program Files/ddev), just run `bash ./windows_ddev_nfs_setup.sh`

Comment: Okay, not sure I could reproduce the steps I used to get there, but in task manager details I see that winnfsd.exe is running. I guess that indicates I have got the script running now, so I will get back to moving forward. Thanks for the help, @rfay!

Comment: @femrich I note that people on Windows with the latest edge versions of Docker are having some trouble with the kinds of things you encountered. Could you report the version of Docker Desktop you were running?

Comment: I am running Docker version 19.03.5, build 633a0ea. I believe it is the stable version. However, I am wrestling with it on multiple levels. Yesterday there was a Windows update that seemed to crash my local site--it would not restart, so I ended up deleting and reinstalling. (No big deal--I am in early stages of site devel; but I would like to focus on the site at some point, and get beyond focusing on the development environment.)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I was actually asking for your Docker Desktop version (something like 2.0.x.x or 2.1.x.x). (Your most likely problem with local project would be that when the system rebooted, your project went to "paused" state. I always recommend `ddev poweroff` before a reboot or messing with docker. Or do it after the reboot works OK too.)

Comment: @ rfay Thanks. As you see, I have lots to learn. But I try to keep a good attitude in the process, and I am grateful for help. Thanks for the tip about pausing--I had not done that, and it makes sense--it was a newbie error that I (hope I) won't make again. I am running Docker Desktop CE 2.1.05 (40693) stable, so my issues are not related to running edge. When running a system that relies on multiple elements working together, finding where the problems are seems to be much of the battle.

Comment: Thanks for that @femrich!